# How can I compare 3 dates using Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I want to compare 3 dates to knowing the lecture is start or not. For that I have created 3 attributes which are lecture_start_date, lecture_finish_date and current date. But when I comparing them I get an error like **strptime() argument 1 must be str, not DeferredAttribute**  but my Lecture.l_date is also string.

Here is the my work

```
def about(request,pk_test):
    classes = Classroom.objects.get(classroom_name=pk_test)
    department = Department.objects.all()
    ads= Ads.objects.all()
    student=Student.objects.all()
    lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
    mydate = datetime.today()
    lecture_start_date = datetime.strptime(Lecture.l_date, '%Y-%m-%`enter code here`d %H:%M:%S')
    lecture_finish_date = datetime.strptime(Lecture.l_date_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if mydate > lecture_start_date and mydate < lecture_finish_date :
         print("The lecture has been started.")
```

In summary, I want to find the lecture is start or not according to the my local time. To find my local time I used mydate = datetime.today() and I have lecture start time and lecture and time which are coming from my database. How can I compare those ?

Comment: What's `Lecture.1_date`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that. Lecture.l_date is a lecture's started date which is coming from database. It's  a DateTimeField.

Comment: @Codeisacode Is it not true that if a lecture didn't start then it didn't finish? since the time for ```lecture_finish_date``` is greater than ```lecture_start_date```. The point is if you want to check if a lecture started you need to compare ```mydate``` with ```lecture_start_date```. For the error it is because you are returning object probably not a string type. I hope this helps.```Lecture.l_date``` and ```Lecture.l_date_end``` are not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the call `Lecture.l_date`, if this is a column in your database you should be getting the value from a specific record instead of getting as a class property.

If you want to get the l_date from the class I suggest you to add a class method into Lecture to be able to get the value you want to compare.

You can achieve this by adding into your model:

```py
@classmethod
def get_l_date(cls):
    # Do the calculations you need to do
    return calculated_date
```

`datetime.strptime` - expects a string as first parameter of the call and that's not what you're passing right now, if you use the approach I suggested before you won't even need this call to convert into a datetime and will be able to do the comparison you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it